# Is decentralized multichain exchange possible using oracles?

Tags: substrate, polkadot

With substrate, we can build our own blockchain, but different blockchain can not communicate with each other, so polkadot is using a relay chain for it. But there is a limit to how many parachain can be attached to the relay chain.
https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/en/learn-auction
Parachain slots are scarce resources and assigned by auction, this creates a barrier of entry for small developers without funding and large resources.
The present decentralized exchange like Uniswap, can't do exchanges beyond their native blockchain.  Some exchanges are trying to use a bridge to talk to another blockchain.
Blockchains that are built on the substrate are different, as they all share the same protocol. Can decentralized exchange enlist any substrate blockchain token without getting a parachain slot? If yes, what are the ways of building it, like using oracles? What will be the security issues?

Well also lower market cap blockchain doesn't seem to be secure enough. So, individual blockchains not included as parachain are unsecure.
https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/en/learn-security

There are pay as you go model as parathread, but 50-100 dots is still expensive, it must compete with the current server prices https://medium.com/polkadot-network/parathreads-pay-as-you-go-parachains-7440d23dde06